# How can an ICommand be executed after the source of a binding is updated?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Say I have a WPF `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Foo}" />
```

Is there a way to execute some `ICommand` after the property `Foo` is updated by the `TextBox` (i.e. is updated specifically by the `TextBox` rather than some other control or code)?

I don't want to use the SourceUpdated event of the binding because I want to avoid "code-behind".

Comment: I'm pretty new to binding myself but I have to ask, why are you trying to avoid code behind?

Comment: Foo won't get updated unless you're doing a Mode=TwoWay binding.

Comment: @lassombra: I want either the code to be in the "ViewModel" or in the .xaml rather than in the .xaml.cs file (an MVVM thing).

Comment: @WilliamMelani: the default mode of the binding varies for each property; for TextBox.Text, it's TwoWay I believe.

Comment: @Ludo learn something everyday!

Comment: @Ludo Then I would just implement the ICommand in your ViewModel and Bind it in your xaml on the SourceUpdated event.  I myself am just learning the MVVM pattern, though I'm discovering piece by piece that for the most part I used a similar pattern during all my WinForms days.

Comment: @lassombra Events cant be bound with ICommand, only Commands can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making a method that does whatever you want to be done and call that method after the raisepropertychanged() is called. For example

```
 public void MyMethod() 
  {
      //Do whatever;

  }
```

And then in your property getter setter:

```
  public string MyText 
  {
    get { return _MyText; }

    set 
    {
       _MyText = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("MyText")
       // THen call that method
       MyMehtod();
    }

   }
```

Syntax may be off, I'm use to doing vb lately. Hope this helps, there are other ways though if you need other options.

Edit 2:

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Foo}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where TextChangedCommand is in your viewmodel

Not sure if TextChanged is an EventName, I dont memorize all the available event types

Comment: Yes I wasn't too clear initially, so I updated my question to say that I want the command to be executed when the update comes from the TextBox and not some other control or code.

Comment: So you want the textbox to specifically call a command after its property is updated?

Comment: except that TextChanged is invoked both ways (i.e. also when the change is from the source); how would I bind to Binding.SourceUpdated event?

Comment: @Ludo. All things being equal (as in its hard to say what the full scope of your intent is so far), Option 1 is actually the more useful way to do this, because you can *test* the logic. You need not worry about the two-way binding in this case since you aren't (I think) changing the bound property.

Comment: @Ludo. suggest you take a step back and write some psuedo code to clarify your intentions. You'll get a way better answer! Cheers

Comment: @Berryl: yes I now believe you are correct about method 1; this is actually what I was already kinda doing by adding properties that encapsulate the "root" property. So yes I'll stick to method 1 especially since, as you mentioned, it improves the quality of the tests since the tests don't need to call that extra command, they just update the extra property. My scenario is to have undo-redo functionality: I need to differentiate an update from the UI from some multi-step operation.

Answer (score 4):

You do realise the MVVM police won't come and get you if do end up having some code behind?  Using event to command etc is essentially just coding in XAML instead of in C# anyway.  Either way you need to hook an event up to a command because the control doesn't expose a command for what you are after.

I think this is what you after, let me know if I'm on the wrong track:

You want to know when the update to Foo comes from the textbox and the textbox only.  i.e. if the update to Foo comes from some code you don't want the command to run, correct?

If so:

```
        <TextBox Name="Fred" Text="{Binding Foo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SourceUpdated="Fred_SourceUpdated"/>
```

Then in the "evil" code behind have:

```
private void Fred_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In that method you can cast the datacontext of the view into the viewmodel and call whatever command you want.  The source updated event will not get called if something else updates Foo.

If you really want to not have code behind as you mention in your OP then you could do an attached behaviour but that is massive overkill for a "nonsense" requirement.  The fact that you logic depends on the whether or not the change comes from the textbox means that your view is more than a view already.  This approach still allows you to have your command code fully testable in you VM.

**2nd edit**

You could also look at using the source updated event in XAML via the event to command rather than text changed

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52821280/1383366

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you just need to handle the `PropertyChanged` event. You execute the command in your event handler. This event handler goes in your ViewModel (not your code behind).

**Edit**

Here is an example of how the EventToCommand behavior in MVVM Light works. You can use this allow any event to be handled with a command.

```
<Rectangle Fill="White"
           Stroke="Black"
           Width="200"
           Height="100">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand,
                                          Mode=OneWay}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding Text,
                                  ElementName=MyTextBox,
                                  Mode=OneWay}"
               MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

**Edit 2**

Another idea would be to always use a method when changing `Foo` via code. This way, you know that any change to `Foo` that doesn't use the method must have been changed by the user.

```
private bool _isFooUpdating;

private void SetFoo(string value)
{
    _isFooUpdating = true;
    Foo = value;
    _isFooUpdating = false;
}

public string Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set
    {
        if (_foo = value) return;
        _foo = value;
        OnFooChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
    }
}

private void OnFooChanged()
{
    if (_isFooUpdating) return;
    FooChangedCommand.Execute();
}
```

Comment: I indeed use INotifyPropertyChanged; now what I'm looking for is a command that is executed specifically when the textbox is the source of the change of Foo.

Comment: In that case, maybe you really do want to handle the event. Are you using MVVM Light? If yes, there is a feature that lets you use commands for any event. I'll add some sample code so you can see how it works.

Comment: I think cmd namespace will be an expression.interactions dll. not sure tho

Comment: Added another edit with a different way of doing it. A little clunky, but should work.